# htaccess 301 redirect with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Iv seen load of htaccess examples and generators to rewrite a url, however I need to put in a 301 redirect for a web app which used to be on a subdomain, but is now in a directory, its also moved from .asp tp .php

the basic redirect is

```
http://sub.domain.com/twforum/forum.asp?FORUM_ID=
```

redirects to

```
http://domain.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=
```

this part i can do, but i dont know how to handle the id (forum id) that will be passed in the url, I DONT want the forum id to be rewritten to a url friendly on, just for it to be carried over/redirected

I assume i need to mod_rewrite the query part.

heres what iv got

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^http://sub.domain.com/twforum/forum.asp?FORUM_ID=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule http://domain.com/forum/viewforum.php\?f=1$ [L,R=301]
```

can anyone see any clear errors there or know of a better way?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{QUERY_STRING}` does not contain the whole of the URL. Just the query setting part. e.g. `FORUM_ID=1`

Assuming that your fourum ids re just numerals.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} FORUM_ID=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/forum/viewforum.php\?f=%1$ [L,R=301]
```